# How can i find the row with the max value in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get which guest spent the most in a hotel throughout their lifetime. The `room` table has the price per individual room.

```
SELECT g.guest_id, g.name, g.email, sum(room_price) sumcost
FROM booking b
INNER JOIN guest g ON b.guest_id = g.guest_id
INNER JOIN room r ON r.room_id = b.room_id
GROUP BY g.guest_id;
```

The above query gives me a list of guests and gets me their sum they spent. Now I need to get only the guest who has the maximum `sumcost` instead of getting the whole list of all the guests. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: order by & limit 1?

Comment: What `MySQL` version are you using? And please add table description , data examples and expected result always when asking a sql question all in text format. You can apply an outer query , you can use limit ...etc. What happen if two guests  have the same max sumcost?

Comment: There may be more than 1 guest with the same maximum amount spent. Mysql version is 8.0.26

Comment: @ErgestBasha, I cannot use a limit since there are more than 1 result. How do I implement an outer query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL select only rows with max value on a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column)

Comment: @craftdeer you can use recursive cte like in this example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04e49734901ae22d7fe4ad8ca7be2b74 , but you haven't updated the question with the needed information to solve the problem, so I only can guess

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   s.ggid,
   s.sumcost
FROM (SELECT 
         g.guest_id ggid, 
         sum(room_price) sumcost
         FROM booking b
         INNER JOIN guest g ON b.guest_id = g.guest_id
         INNER JOIN room r ON r.room_id = b.room_id
         GROUP BY g.guest_id
         ORDER BY sumcost  DESC) s
WHERE s.sumcost = ( SELECT sum(room_price) sumcost
                    FROM booking b
                    INNER JOIN guest g ON b.guest_id = g.guest_id
                    INNER JOIN room r ON r.room_id = b.room_id
                    GROUP BY g.guest_id
                    ORDER BY sumcost DESC
                    LIMIT 1
                   )
```

Comment: Thank. But there might be more than 1 guest with the same max amount spent. Is there any way to handle that?

Comment: @craftdeer I just edited the ORDER BY to handle that possibility. Can you try it out on a known dataset with more than one guest with the same sumcost value?

Comment: It works. But there are 3 people with the same `sumnum`. There may be more in the future. I am wondering if we can use the MAX function somehow

Comment: @craftdeer, I understand, I don't think my solution will handle that. I'm thinking we may need to do a subquery with a MAX function, as you suggest, in the outer query.

Comment: @craftdeer, I've completely rewritten this with subqueries to handle the situation where there are multiple guests with the same max amount spent. However, I'm not sure this is optimized. Perhaps other experts can improve this to be simpler and faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function, e.g. `MAX OVER`:

```
SELECT g.guest_id, g.name, g.email, sums.sumcost
FROM guest g
JOIN
(
  SELECT
    b.guest_id, SUM(r.room_price) AS sumcost,
    MAX(SUM(r.room_price)) OVER () AS maxsumcost
  FROM booking b
  INNER JOIN room r ON r.room_id = b.room_id
  GROUP BY b.guest_id
) sums ON sums.guest_id = g.guest_id AND sums.sumcost = maxsumcost;
```

Comment: Does the `GROUP BY` in the subquery need to be `b.guest_id` instead of `g.guest_id`? @ThorstenKettner